# Python; different result depending if I put a variable or directly the value in parameter

Tags: python, matrix

I have a function creating a matrix and another one that changes a value in the matrix. If I use the matrix created in the first function as a parameter for the second one, I have a different result that if I write the matrix directly.

Code:

```
test = createBoard(2,2)               #the parameters are the dimensions
print(type(test))
print(test)

setBoardXY(test, 1, 0, 2)                # (matrix,x,y,value to change)
setBoardXY([[0,0],[0,0]],1,0,2)
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 2], [0, 2]]
[[0, 2], [0, 0]]
```

'''

As you can see for the same matrix in parameter the result is not the same.

The function if you want to see it

```
def setBoardXY(board, x, y, value):
    for line in board:
        if x >= len(line) or x < 0 or y >= len(board) or y < 0:
            print(board)
            return board
        else:
            board[y][x] = value
            print(board)
            return board
```

I really don t understand why the same function with the same parameters doesn't have the same result. Thanks by advance

**EDIT**: apparently it could be coming from the function createBoard, where all rows are referred to.

```
def createBoard(DIMX, DIMY):
matrix = []
X = []
i = 0
while i != DIMX :
    X.append(0)
    i+=1
while len(matrix) != DIMY :
    matrix.append(X)
return matrix
```

Comment: The problem is in the createBoard method, which you haven't shown. In that function you return the list  where all rows are actually a reference to the same row. That's why when you modify any row the change is applied to all rows.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i put the function in the question if you want to take a look. Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a copy of your list so that you get a separate object.

```
def createBoard(DIMX, DIMY):
    matrix = []
    X = []
    i = 0
    while i != DIMX :
        X.append(0)
        i+=1
    while len(matrix) != DIMY :
        matrix.append(X.copy())
    return matrix
```

Comment: it is working now, the problem was indeed that i needed to use a copy of X. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The list you changing in `setBoardXY` is not a new list. It is just a reference to the list you created with `createBoard`. You could fix your problem with the function below. It creates a new list `board` which can then be safely mutated without having any unwanted side-effects.

```
def setBoardXY(old_board, x, y, value):
    board = [d[:] for d in old_board]
    for line in board:
        if x >= len(line) or x < 0 or y >= len(board) or y < 0:
            print(board)
            return board
        else:
            board[y][x] = value
            print(board)
            return board
```

In general Python names are just references. The only exceptions are integers, floats, strings, and tuples. They will not be mutated (so if you use an expression that re-assigns them, it will create a new object.)